# Adding a view desktop link to mobile site

Tags: redirection, mobile-tools

I am using X-AH-Mobile-Redirect in the settings.php file to redirect visitors to the mobile site. I need to add a link so that visitors can switch to the desktop site.

Here is a snippet of the redirect code:

```
    if (isset($_ENV['AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT'])) {
  switch ($_ENV['AH_SITE_ENVIRONMENT']) {
case 'dev':
   header('X-AH-Mobile-Redirect: http://m.mysite.com');
  break;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about X-AH-Mobile-Redirect, but I did this a while ago by creating a link like http://example.com/?device=desktop and on page load I would check for $_GET['device'] and for a cookie

Then I could just check

```
if (isset($_GET['device']) && $_GET['device'] == 'desktop') {
    setcookie('mycookie', 'true', strtotime('+365 days'));
    $mobile_browser = 0; //This forces site into desktop mode
}
```

Then on desktop version you just go the other way around with a http://example.com/?device=mobile

```
if (isset($_GET['device']) && $_GET['device'] == 'mobile') {
    setcookie('mycookie', null, -1); //Unset cookie
}
```

Of course you have to add whatever you need to force your mobile detector to go into mobile/desktop version, but it's pretty much it, on page loads check for the cookie and for the query strings and act accordingly.